# How can I print all eli5.explain_weights() results without ellipsis?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I want to print the feature importance of all the features but I'm keep on getting only first few.

Functions I've tried:

```
print(eli5.format_as_text(eli5.explain_weights(perm)))
```

and

```
print(eli5.format_as_html(eli5.explain_weights(perm)))
```

and also the show option on the format functions, `show=("WEIGHTS", "ALL")` but they all only print first few answers and then omits the rest with ellipsis like the following:

```
0.0955 ± 0.1404  x23
0.0490 ± 0.0661  x33
0.0401 ± 0.0253  x64
0.0324 ± 0.0245  x37
0.0263 ± 0.0480  x111
0.0253 ± 0.0057  x107
0.0248 ± 0.0237  x36
0.0245 ± 0.0265  x81
0.0209 ± 0.0173  x46
0.0139 ± 0.0129  x80
0.0126 ± 0.0121  x14
0.0125 ± 0.0182  x1
0.0122 ± 0.0110  x110
0.0113 ± 0.0135  x51
0.0113 ± 0.0198  x116
0.0106 ± 0.0063  x11
0.0104 ± 0.0153  x66
0.0088 ± 0.0278  x113
0.0086 ± 0.0236  x67
0.0085 ± 0.0194  x21
    … 101 more …
```

Is there a way to print everything?

Comment: Well I found the culprit line, I'll dig in more to see if there's a setting: see `_format_remaining` in the docs https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/eli5/formatters/text.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass the attribute `top=100` to `explain_weights` like `eli5.explain_weights(perm, top=100)`

https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autodocs/eli5.html?highlight=top

It looks like the default is 20: https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/eli5/sklearn/explain_weights.html?highlight=_TOP

see `_TOP=20`

Comment: o, never thought the limit would be in explain_weights. thank you. it works great!